# Extract substring from Splunk String

Tags: regex, splunk

I have a field "hostname" in splunk logs which is available in my event as
"host = server.region.ab1dc2.mydomain.com".

I can refer to host with same name "host" in splunk query. I want to extract the substring with 4 digits after two dots ,for the above example , it will be "ab1d". How my splunk query should look like for this extraction?

Basically I have been given a string, and want to skip two dots and then take the four characters after that.

Answer (score 2):

So long as you have at least three segments to a fully-qualified domain name, this should work (without using a regular expression)

```
index=ndx sourcetype=srctp host=*
| makemv delim="." host
| eval piece=substr(mvindex(host,3),1,4)
...
```

[`makemv`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/makemv) converts a field into a multivalue field based on the `delim` you instruct it to use

Then use [`eval`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/eval) to grab the third item in the list using [`mvindex`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/MultivalueEvalFunctions#mvindex.28MVFIELD.2CSTARTINDEX.2C_ENDINDEX.29), trimming it with [`substr`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/TextFunctions#substr.28X.2CY.2CZ.29)

If you *really* want to use a regular expression, [this](https://regex101.com/r/GQIlFf/1) will do it (again, presuming you have at least three pieces to the FQDN):

```
index=ndx sourcetype=srctp host=*
| rex field=host "\.[^\.]+\.(?<piece>[^\.]{4})"
...
```